# Updating Value in Series Based on Another Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to update a `series` based on a shorter `series`.

```
t
0    1
1    3
2    4
3    2
4    4
Name: rank, dtype: int32 

Vtk
1    4
2    3
4    3
Name: rank, dtype: int64
```

I'm expecting the output like :

```
t
0    1
1    4
2    3
3    2
4    3
Name: rank, dtype: int32
```

After I ran

```
t = t.update(Vtk)
print(t)
```

It shows that *t* is a none value.

```
t
None
```

Am I using the `.update` method wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: What happens if you read the manual and try `t.update()` without assignment? Did you think about it being a inplace operation instead of returning anything?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html  :  `Modify  ****in place**** using non-NA values from another DataFrame.` Same for https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html: `Modify Series ***in place*** using non-NA values from passed Series.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function [`Series.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html) working inplace, so it return `None`:

> **Series.update(other)** 
>   Modify Series in place using non-NA values from passed Series. Aligns on index.

```
print(t.update(Vtk))
None
```

So dont assign back:

```
t.update(Vtk)
print (t)
0    1
1    4
2    3
3    2
4    3
dtype: int64
```